# airflow experimental API deny_all module not found

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow.
I wanted to not import any feature of experimental API. So I had followed the [instructions](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html#authentication) and edited my airflow.cfg config file.

```
[api]
# How to authenticate users of the API
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all
```

But I had the following error when I started my airflow webserver.

```
Cannot import airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all for API authentication due to: No module named 'airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all'
```

Help me guys.
my airflow version is v1.8.0

Answer (score 2):

The module airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all is on v1-10. In airflow v1.8 this module wasn't developed yet
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/airflow-fork-k1/v1-8-stable/airflow-fork-k1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since `deny_all` backend is only available since v1.10, you have two options:

1. Upgrade Airflow to v1.10 (**recommended**)
2. If for some reason you can't upgrade, you can create your own backport as described below.

#### Backporting `deny_all` backend from v1.10 to v1.8

Create a new file in your project, e.g. `deny_all_auth_backend.py`, and copy paste the [deny_all.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/auth/backend/deny_all.py) contents inside:

```py
from functools import wraps
from flask import Response

client_auth = None


def init_app(app):
    pass


def requires_authentication(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        return Response("Forbidden", 403)

    return decorated
```

Then configure Airflow to use this backend via `airflow.cfg`:

```
[api]
auth_backend = my_app.deny_all_auth_backend  # or the actual path to your module
```